# Remove "Generated" labels in schemacrawler

Tags: schemacrawler

In schemacrawler, is there an option to remove the "Generated by Schemacrawler" and "Generated on ..." labels? I've checked the documentation and failed to find this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - use the `--no-info` command-line switch.